Limit audio interface to mono recording in pipewire
Is there any way of forcing my audio interface to give a mono "signal" instead of stereo using pipewire?
I narrate audio books and use Linux Mint with Ubuntu studio software installed ”on top”. My audio interface is a Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 (3rd gen), that has two inputs. When recording I need to use special software, so no real DAW, provided by my employer, where one is a piece of old software that needs to run in Windows XP in Virtualbox and the other is a recording plugin for chrome.
One problem with this is that both Virtualbox and the chrome plugin have problems handling the fact that my audio interface has two input channels which leads to them only receiving audio from my microphone through the left stereo input channel. I have so far managed to solve this by setting the pulse_in Bridge Channel Count to 1 in Ubuntu Studio Controls (under Pulse Bridging), which means that both Virtualbox and the plugin gets a mono signal that they understand.
Now: I am thinking of giving a clean install of Ubuntu Studio 24.04 LTS a go, but I have had problems achieving the same thing using pipewire in the past, when I've tried. It seems that pipewire is the future, though.
So I want to sort this out, but I freely admit that my eyes glaze over when I try to understand the differences between pulseaudio, jack and pipewire and which settings (bridges, sinks, channels etc) I need to change where and by what means (.lua-files, wireplumber, qjackctl etc)... If someone just could give me a fish and tell me what to do, it would be greatly appreciated, but just giving me a pointer to resources that teach me to fish, ie explains what I need to know to acheive this myself it would of course be even more appreciated!

What I ended up doing was create a "dummy" device with one input and two outputs and then I used pwvucontrol to set that device as default source for both chrome and Virtualbox. It works for now at least!

The programme QJackCtl or qpwgraph are graphical interfaces that allow you to draw connections between inputs and outputs. So you would draw a connection from the left output of your interface into the audio input of your other program. If you don't connect the right output, the receiver doesn't know it exists.
This is a much simpler system than the old way and things like sinks and bridges between things are no longer required.

Thank you for replying, and sorry for taking so long to reply!
This does not work for me, unfortunately... When I start to record in VirtualBox a box named "VirtualBox" with stereo inputs and outputs appears and connects to the FL and RL outputs of my interface. This leads to the recorded audio in Virtualbox being just the left channel. I can change this to the configuration I want when recording, but it snaps back every time I stop recording (the VirtualBox box disappears in qpwgraph/Carla when I stop recording).

This "disappearing item" thing in pipewire is intensely frustrating!!! If you find a solution, please reply here. There might be a setting on VirtualBox to keep audio always on. That's a virtualbox question, though, so it could be worthwhile to ask again.
